# Submit form redirect variable

Tags: php, html, wordpress, post

I'm trying get a form to redirect to a certain page depending on what option is chosen in a select div. When I press submit, it redirects to the home page. I realize it's because it doesn't change $industry_choice until after the I press the button... is there a method to change this the moment you select a value?

Let's say I choose banking, and $industry_choice = "banking".

```
if(empty($_POST['industry'])) {
                                $industry_choice = "";
                        } else {
                                $industry_choice = $_POST['industry'];
                        }
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/<?php echo $industry_choice ?>">
                        <select name="industry">
                                (lots of options here)
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" class="select-industry" value="Select">
                </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. I think you are not clear with the `action` attibute of the form.

```
<?php


if(empty($_POST['industry'])) {
                                $industry_choice = "";
                        } else {
                                $industry_choice = $_POST['industry'];
                header('Location: http://localhost:8888/wordpress/'.$industry_choice);
                        }

?>


<form method="post" action="">
                        <select name="industry">
                       (options)
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" class="select-industry" value="Select">
                </form>
```

`action` attribute will redirect to the page you processed the input. After that you will redirect it to targeted location.